# Error 1359 Setting Bluetooth Radio Mode Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5

Tags: .net, bluetooth, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, 32feet

Using [In The Hand 32feet library](https://github.com/inthehand) for .NET Compact Framework 3.5, when runing their sample project [Chat2Device](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothChat2/Chat2Device) on a Datalogic Scorpio X3 running Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Professional CE OS 5.2.29366 Build 29366.5.3.12.48 the command to switch Bluetooth radio to "Discoverable" fails. I added some additional error reporting code and found the native error code is 1359 (Internal Error Occurred?)

There is no problem communicating between devices using Bluetooth within this sample project on the mobile device, only retrieving PrimaryRadio info or attempting to set RadioMode to any mode throws exception.

Full error message is:

Win32Exception
Error setting BluetoothRadio Error Code 1359 at InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Msft.WindowsBluetoothRadio.set_Mode(RadioMode value)

Code is:

```
BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Discoverable;
```

The following code in the sample also fails with similar exception:

```
var myRadio = BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio;
            if (myRadio == null) {
                wtr.WriteLine("No radio hardware or unsupported software stack");
                return;
            }
            var mode = myRadio.Mode;
            // Warning: LocalAddress is null if the radio is powered-off.
            wtr.WriteLine("* Radio, address: {0:C}", myRadio.LocalAddress);
            wtr.WriteLine("Mode: " + mode.ToString());
            wtr.WriteLine("Name: " + myRadio.Name);
            wtr.WriteLine("HCI Version: " + myRadio.HciVersion
                + ", Revision: " + myRadio.HciRevision);
            wtr.WriteLine("LMP Version: " + myRadio.LmpVersion
                + ", Subversion: " + myRadio.LmpSubversion);
            wtr.WriteLine("ClassOfDevice: " + myRadio.ClassOfDevice
                + ", device: " + myRadio.ClassOfDevice.Device
                + " / service: " + myRadio.ClassOfDevice.Service);
            wtr.WriteLine("S/W Manuf: " + myRadio.SoftwareManufacturer);
            wtr.WriteLine("H/W Manuf: " + myRadio.Manufacturer);
```

Any suggestions for a fix, or alternate method to set the radio to discoverable programatically.

The relevant sections of library code;

```
private const string btdrtDll = "btdrt.dll";

[DllImport(btdrtDll, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int BthReadScanEnableMask(out WinCeScanMask pmask);

[DllImport(btdrtDll, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int BthWriteScanEnableMask(WinCeScanMask mask);        

[Flags()]
internal enum WinCeScanMask : byte
{
    None = 0,
    InquiryScan = 1,
    PageScan = 2,
}

public void SetMode(bool? connectable, bool? discoverable)
{
    // TO-DO set power-on here
    //
    WinCeScanMask mask;
    if (connectable.HasValue && discoverable.HasValue) {
        // Will set both bits so do NOT need to know their current value.
        mask = 0;
    } else {
        int resultR = NativeMethods.BthReadScanEnableMask(out mask);
        if (resultR != 0) {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(resultR, "Error getting BluetoothRadio mode");
        }
    }
    switch (connectable) {
        case true:
            mask |= WinCeScanMask.PageScan;
            break;
        case false:
            mask &= ~WinCeScanMask.PageScan;
            break;
        // null NOP
    }
    switch (discoverable) {
        case true:
            mask |= WinCeScanMask.InquiryScan;
            break;
        case false:
            mask &= ~WinCeScanMask.InquiryScan;
            break;
        // null NOP
    }
    var result = NativeMethods.BthWriteScanEnableMask(mask);
    if (result != 0) {
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(result, "Error setting BluetoothRadio mode");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure for the "Datalogic Scorpio X3" with WEH65, but some devices come with a non-MS Bluetooth stack.

AFAIS, the "Datalogic Scorpio X3" SDK provides an unique API set for controlling Bluetooth.

The standard function to set the BT modul mode is [BthSetMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916815.aspx). The other function [BthWriteScanEnableMask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms887900.aspx) is used by 32feet. Which probably is not implemented on the Datalogic X3.

Comment: Thanks I tried BthSetMode but it also returns 1359. I downloaded Datalogic SDK and it does have bluetooth API bur from what I can see doesn't offer option to set radio mode. I think I need to work out what the Bluetooth Manager "Find Me" button uses...